# Single node Presto setup on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, presto

I am trying to set Presto db on my Ubuntu VM. Despite following all the steps from this link: https://prestodb.io/docs/current/installation/deployment.html , I am not able to get an instance of it up and running.
When I do ./bin/presto-cli --server localhost:8181 - I am taken to the presto command line, but I get this error: Error running command: Server refused connection: http://localhost:8181/v1/statement , when I do a show catalog or any other command.

I would be greatful if some one could point me in the right direction here.

Thank you,

Comment: What is the error / log output you get when you start the presto server?

Comment: Solved, it was easy, I had not configured the connectors properly.